# How to quickly reference the same cell across different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 60 Sheets with the same information but for different employees. I was wanting to create a summary sheet but without manually linking.

In the summary sheet, I want cell A6 from each sheet to appear in cells B1:B60. I tried entering 1 through 60 in cells A1:A60 and then using

```
=CONCATENATE("Sheet",A1,"!A6")
```

so that I could drag it down easily but it just returns `Sheet1!A6`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Surround that formula with `INDIRECT(...)`

Comment: Should this be deleted if it's duplicate? I searched but didn't come across that one.

Comment: Yes, but it looks like people have already started the 'flag as duplicate' process. You don't need to do anything else.